# C# and EF not able to add related entities to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to get a list of Posts including the Tags.

I have the **Model**:

```
public class BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<BlogTagGetByPostIdDto> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class BlogTagGetByPostIdDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
}
```

My Code so far:

```
public BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto GetByUrlSlug(string urlSlug)
{
    var blogPostQuery = _blogPostRepository.Query;

    return blogPostQuery
                .Where(b => b.UrlSlug.Equals(urlSlug))
                .ToList()
                .Select(bp => new BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto 
                { 
                    Id = bp.Id, 
                    Title = bp.Title, 
                    Category = bp.BlogCategory.Name, 
                    Color = bp.BlogCategory.Color, 
                    UrlSlug = bp.UrlSlug, 
                    Description = bp.Description,
                    Tags = bp.BlogTags.Select(t => new BlogTagGetByPostIdDto 
                                        { 
                                            Name = t.Name, 
                                            UrlSlug = t.UrlSlug
                                        })
                                        .ToList() 
                })
                .Single();
}
```

I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` in the line `.Select(bp => new BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto`.

Any idea why?

The **Repository** for `_blogPostRepository.Query` is:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T FindById(int id, bool asNoTracking = false);

    T FindSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, bool asNoTracking = false, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);

    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, bool asNoTracking = false, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);


    /// <summary> 
    /// Add entity to the repository 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="entity">The entity to add</param> 
    void Add(T entity);

    /// <summary> 
    /// Attach entity to the repository 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="entity">The entity to attach</param> 
    void Attach(T entity);

    bool Exists(T entity);

    /// <summary> 
    /// Updates entity within the repository 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="entity">The entity to update</param> 
    void Update(T entity, bool partial = false);


    /// <summary> 
    /// Mark entity by id to be deleted within the repository 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="entity">The entity to delete</param> 
    void Delete(object id);


    /// <summary> 
    /// Mark entity to be deleted within the repository 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="entity">The entity to delete</param> 
    void Delete(T entity);


    /// <summary>
    /// Get an item matching the id
    /// </summary>
    T GetById(int id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get an item or itens matching the Expression including opcional parameters 
    /// </summary>
    IList<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");

    /// <summary>
    /// Get an item matching to prediate
    /// </summary>
    //T Get(Func<T, bool> predicate);


    /// <summary>
    /// Get all the itens matching to prediate
    /// </summary>
    IList<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> predicate);


    ///// <summary>
    ///// Get all the element of this repository
    ///// </summary>
    ///// <returns>Entities list</returns>
    IList<T> GetAll();


    /// <summary>
    /// Allow to send Linq queries to the entity
    /// </summary>
    IQueryable<T> Query { get; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the pending changes back into the DataContext.
    /// </summary>
    void Save();
}
```

Implementation of the Query:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbContext _dataContext;
    protected DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Query
    {
        get
        {
            return _dbSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `blogPostQuery`? Or maybe I should ask: what happens in the `_blogPostRepository.Query` property? If you'd return the original EF query you probably wouldn't have a null reference exception.

Comment: Hi Thanks. blogPostQuery is type IRepository<BlogPost> _blogPostRepository; where in my repository I have all the operations over EF like Add Attach Exists Update but no Include :(

Comment: You have to return the original `IQueryable` from EF, otherwise the internal query will always return *all* records. You can't use projections or predicates that are translated back into the SQL and reduce the payload and you can't compose queries from multiple repositories in a way that one SQL query is generated. And there's no `Include`, no `AsNoTracking`. You're applying LINQ-to-objects to an oversized query result, hence the null object reference (a `bp.BlogTags`). In SQL this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Any example you can give me to help me?

Comment: Pleas show exactly what happens in `_blogPostRepository.Query` and show the definition of `IRepository<T>`. Maybe I'll be able to show by example what is wrong here.

Comment: I have updated the question with the repository.

Comment: And the implementation of `Query`?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I have completed the question with the implementation of  Query.

Comment: So basically you're querying a `DbSet`. That means that the whole query should get translated into SQL and executed by the database, so you shouldn't get null reference exceptions. In other words: I don't understand this. Is there any SQL that runs while the statement is executed?

Answer (score 5):

To load entities within the main query, (this process is called [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)), you can use the [`Include()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include(v=vs.103).aspx) and pass your collection as an expression.

To use some extensions of Entity Framework, remember to add the following namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

For sample, try something like this:

```
var result = _blogPostRepository.Query
                               .Where(b => b.UrlSlug.Equals(urlSlug))
                               .Include(b => b.Tags) 
                               .Select(bp => new BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto 
                                { 
                                    Id = bp.Id, 
                                    Title = bp.Title, 
                                    Category = bp.BlogCategory.Name, 
                                    Color = bp.BlogCategory.Color, 
                                    UrlSlug = bp.UrlSlug, 
                                    Description = bp.Description,
                                    Tags = bp.Tags.Select(t => new BlogTagGetByPostIdDto 
                                                        { 
                                                            Name = t.Name, 
                                                            UrlSlug = t.UrlSlug
                                                        })
                                })
                                .FirstOrDefault();

return result;
```

Since you call `ToList` or `Single` or `FistOrDefault` methods, it will execute the query into the database. In your code, you call the `ToList()` and it will execute the query in database and execute each query (lazy loading) for tags.

Read this article to know more about how to lead with Earger/Lazy loading.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Hi thanks! In your opinion what is the best option? with the ToList() to execute in memory or without to execute in database?

Comment: ToList will execute in the database and everything you do after ToList, it will be on memory. I think would be better you try to load Tags using Include method and after it call `FirstOrDefault` (which return null if any register is not found) instead calling ToList and Single.

Comment: I don't have access to the ".Include" because I use a Repository that use the interface IQueryable<T> Query { get; } for the blogPostQuery variable.

Comment: @Patrick - and now you know why generic repositories are a bad idea.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Hi, any better suggestion?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx
Include is also available for IQueryable. Check that you have all namespaces included.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use .Include with IQueryable but you should add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

as it's an IQueryable extension method.

Method specification:
[DbExtensions.Include Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include(v=vs.103).aspx)

---

Besides that, you should check if **BlogCategory can be null**, if that's the case you need to deal with it in your Select, otherwise it will be null and throw the error as you're trying to access a property of a null object.

Something like:

```
public BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto GetByUrlSlug(string urlSlug)
{
    var blogPostQuery = _blogPostRepository.Query;

    return blogPostQuery
                .Where(b => b.UrlSlug.Equals(urlSlug))
                .Include(b => b.Tags)
                .Select(bp => new BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto 
                { 
                    Id = bp.Id, 
                    Title = bp.Title, 
                    Category = bp.BlogCategory == null ? string.Empty : bp.BlogCategory.Name, 
                    Color = bp.BlogCategory == null ? string.Empty : bp.BlogCategory.Color, 
                    UrlSlug = bp.UrlSlug, 
                    Description = bp.Description,
                    Tags = bp.BlogTags.Select(t => new BlogTagGetByPostIdDto 
                                        { 
                                            Name = t.Name, 
                                            UrlSlug = t.UrlSlug
                                        })
                                        .ToList() 
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Tags` collection in `BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto` to this (the virtual keyword is required):

```
public virtual ICollection<BlogTagGetByPostIdDto> Tags { get; set; }
```

This is neccessary for Lazy Loading to work. The `BlogTagGetByPostIdDto` class also needs a primary key, so change it to this:

```
public class BlogTagGetByPostIdDto
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
}
```

If you do not want name to be unique, add an ID property to this class.
When you have now retrieved a `BlogPostGetByUrlSlugDto` object, and you use the `Tags` property, it will retrieve the Tags associated with this object.